# Adding and dividing numbers based on cell color

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to do some calculation based on color codes but I have not been able to figure it out. Essentially, what I want to do is to automatically obtain the average number based on assigned values to colors. As shown in the picture, I want to assign 1 to red, 2 to amber and 3 to blue and then add up and divide by the count to get the average (I manually calculated it in cells B10 and C10 below). I am not sure if there are in-built functions that can help achieve this or if there is a VBA code that can do this. I came up with this code but it's not giving me the desired result.

```
Option Explicit

Function SumColor(sumRange As Range) As Double
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In sumRange
If cell.Interior.Color = 16777215 Then
SumColor = 1
End If
Next cell
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: You set the color via conditional formatting?

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT((((B3:B8>=.9)*3)+((B3:B8>=.7)*(B3:B8<.9)*2)+(B3:B8<.7))*B3:B8)/6`?

Comment: or if you only want the average of {3,2,3,1,2,3}: `=SUMPRODUCT((((B3:B8>=0.9)*3)+((B3:B8>=0.7)*(B3:B8<0.9)*2)+(B3:B8<0.7)))/6`

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to automate this to address for cases where is a merged cell in the range? Also, is it possible to automate the denominator to count cells within the range. For now, we have it as 8 but a new row could be added which would mean we have to manually change the denominator? Any ideas?